# Raspberry Pi boot time issue

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, systemd, services, systemd-startup

I am using Raspberry pi 3b+ and trying to reduce the boot time from power-on, till the GUI is shown(desktop mode).
What basically happens is after power-on it takes some time to show the splash screen and then the GUI.

Now in order to reduce the boot time, I disabled some of the services like Bluetooth, hciuart, Networking and dhcpcd.
What I noticed is :

**before disabling the services:-**
time from power on to gui= 30seconds
with

```
systemd-analyze:
```

3.76s(kernel) + 19.956s(userspace)
graphical.target reached after 10.299s

**After disabling the services :-**
time from power on to gui= 30seconds

but with

```
systemd-analyze:
```

3.76s(kernel) + 13.956s(userspace)
graphical.target reached after 9.299s

I am just curios how the time remains same but in systemd-analyze there is a difference of nearly 7 seconds